# Is it possible to design a UI in WPF that has the flip animation like in windows phone?

Tags: c#, wpf, uwp

I want to design a UI to show the usage of the meeting rooms. I have a main Window like the following, and I want the blocks of the rooms flip (like in the Windows Phone) every 10 seconds, to show until when the room is used.

[image]

Figure 1. The Window before flips.

[image]

Figure 2. The Window after flips, namely after 10 seconds

[image]

Figure 3. Add a new room Room7

So is it possible to design this in WPF? Or must I use UWP in Windows 10? The problem is that there are still some computers in my company that only have windows 7. So I think there may be a problem.

Secondly, if we in the future add new rooms, I also want the UI has the ability, that the User can type in the new room and the UI will accept it and change its structure accordingly. For example, to look it in a simple way, every time a new room is added, the height of Room6 is divided by 2 , 3 ... , and the new Room will be shown in the place of Room6. As shown in Figure 3.

Is this possible?

Thanks.

Comment: Is this possible? -> Yes.

Comment: There are animations in WPF and there are plenty of tutorials around the web. It's worth to try something and if you stuck we will help you gladly. Make sure to include your attempt in the next question. *"must I use UWP in Windows 10"*? Not really, WPF is working amazing on win10 and win7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few questions here and I'll try answer some:

First - Yes, you definitely can!

And here is how:

1. The solution to display all rooms dynamically while adding and removing rooms can be solved like so:
   A WrapPanel with Orientation of Horizontal that each of its items is a WrapPanel with Orientation of Vertical. Each item of the inner WrapPanel is the RoomModel. This will create a table or a two dimensional array which will allow you to rearrange the Columns and Rows (on the ViewModel) of that table whenever a Room is added or removed according to a specific logic of your choice.
2. The dynamic display of the statuses - All information of every room including its state which will be exposed by the RoomModel with a string property let's say: DisplayedState. Through simple binding, whenever the state changes, the displayed state is chenged.
3. A simple timer can check for changes on the Server side, and if there are any, it will rearrange the rooms and statuses.

It will look something like that:

```
           <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding RoomColumns}" >
                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>

                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate >
                        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding RoomModel}" >
                            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

                                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                    <WrapPanel Orientation="Vertical" />
                                </ItemsPanelTemplate>

                            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

                            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate >
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding DisplayedState}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
```

RoomColumns is

```
ObservableCollection<ObservableCollection<RoomModel>>
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thx for your detailed answer!

Comment: @DexterLiu You are welcome! If this answered your question, please mark it as so for others to see and understand as well :)